# Nightwatch variable scope and accessing outside .element call

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have the following method in my Nightwatch test that does not work as expected:

```
function checkCategoryRows(browser, theOptionText, rows) {
    var isGood = true;
    rows.value.forEach(function (row) {
        browser.elementIdText(row.ELEMENT, function (categoryText) {
            if (categoryText.value != theOptionText) {
                browser.verify.ok(0 == 1, categoryText.value + ' = ' + theOptionText);
                isGood = false;
            } else 
                isGood = false; //<-- Manually making sure it sets either way
        })
    })
    browser.verify.ok(isGood == true, theOptionText + ' category is good...');
}
```

> isGood

is always true; even if I set it manually. It appears that anything inside the `browser.element(){}` call is only scoped inside that call.
How do I get this to work so at the end of the `for loop` I can show that something was 'not good' in that particular set of rows?

Comment: I think all you need to do is instantiate that variable outside the function scope so it's global.

Also, notice that your parentheses after the else is not necessary, and must be moved to the last bracket to close the foreach -- unless this is incomplete code and there is more to that function, let us know

Comment: Scope isn't the issue. I suspect `elementIdText` is asynchronous, and your verification runs before the callbacks do.

Comment: @chrismillah the parenthesis is necessary. It closes the browser.element call preceeding it. The else has no brackets at all since it is one line. JS allows you to no put curly brackets on conditionals if the condition is only one line.

Comment: @AuxTaco DO you happen to know how to make a Nightwatch command run synchronously?

Comment: @chrismillah I put an extra curly in there by mistake, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in Nightwatch, there is no 'document' or 'window' object. There is a 'browser' object that seems to be similar. Here is how I solved it:

```
function checkCategoryRows(browser, theOptionText, rows) {
     browser.isGood = true;
     rows.value.forEach(function (row) {
         browser.elementIdText(row.ELEMENT, function (categoryText) {
             //console.info(categoryText)
             if (categoryText.value != theOptionText) {
                 browser.verify.ok(0 == 1, categoryText.value + ' = ' + theOptionText);
                 browser.isGood = false;
             }
             //else
             //    browser.isGood = false; // for testing
             console.log('browser.isGood=' + browser.isGood);
         })
     })
     browser.verify.ok(browser.isGood == true, theOptionText + ' category is good...');
}
```

Setting `browser.isGood = true;` initially made it available to the rest of the method.